# GET parameters are lost when submitting a form with POST method in CGI?

Tags: perl, cgi

```
<form method="POST" action="/index?key=1">
<input type="text" name="another_key" value="2" />
</form>
```

When I submit such a form and trying to fetch the `GET` parameter with `CGI->new->param('key')`,

it doesn't work..

Can CGI work when both `GET` and `POST` parameters exist?

Comment: I haven't worked with CGI, but why don't you settle with either `GET` or `POST`. If you are performing some lookup operation, use GET and if you are going to write to some databse, use POST.

Comment: @silverback, he's always doing a POST.  He just wants to include some parameters in the URL (like you would in a GET).  There's no rule that says your POST URL can't have a query component.  The question here is how can you access the parameters from that query component.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a POST request, CGI's param method will only get post parameters, but there is an alternate url_param method that will provide the "GET" parameters from the url.

This can be very helpful for file uploads; if the post request is too large, it will be entirely discarded, but the url parameters can tell you what kind of upload it was so you can show the user an error message in the correct context.